# How to create choropleth map using bokeh if region boundaries are not known

Tags: python, bokeh, openstreetmap, choropleth

I have coordinate data with following columns:
`lat | lon | hits`

I want to plot a choropleth using these data with color on the basis of hits, on top of OSM tile.

```
plot = figure(
    tools= "pan,wheel_zoom",
    x_range=[8580732.740161393, 8694052.230954666],
    y_range=[3324832.84084286, 3580909.760461876])
plot.add_tile(get_provider(Vendors.OSM))
```

Till now what I have learned is we need boundaries of regions which are colored, but I don't have geojson for locality boundaries in smaller cities of India. Is there any way possible to plot choropleth using square/rectangular grids or clustering the coordinates?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing in Bokeh that will do automatic binning is `hexbin`:

```
import numpy as np
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show

n = 500
x = 2 + 2*np.random.standard_normal(n)
y = 2 + 2*np.random.standard_normal(n)

p = figure(match_aspect=True, background_fill_color='#440154')
p.grid.visible = False

r, bins = p.hexbin(x, y, size=0.5, hover_color="pink", hover_alpha=0.8)

p.circle(x, y, color="white", size=1)

show(p)
```

[image]

If you want something besides hex tiles, you would have to define the boundaries/regions you want explicitly, and bin inside them yourself.